Cellular maps of CW-complexes and CW-pairs
A map of CW-complexes $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ is cellular if $f(X^n) \subset Y^n$ and a map
of CW-pairs $f: (X,A) \longrightarrow (Y,B)$ is cellular if $f(X^n \cup A) \subset Y^n \cup B$.
Obviously given a map of pairs $f: (X,A) \longrightarrow (Y,B)$ that is cellular on the absolute level, that is, $f(X^n) \subset Y^n$, then $f(X^n \cup A) = f(X^n) \cup f(A) \subset Y^n \cup B$ and $f$ is cellular as a map of pairs.
Is there a converse statement? Does a cellular map of pairs with $f(X^n \cup A)  \subset Y^n \cup B$ imply a cellular map $f(X^n) \subset Y^n$ on the  absolute level?

Where is this definition of a cellular map of CW-pairs from? I haven't seen it defined like that in the literature and I also personally don't agree with it.

It sounds like you may have mixed up "cellular maps of CW-pairs" with "cellular maps of relative CW-complexes." The way you've written it the converse is false and you should have no trouble coming up with a counterexample on your own.

The definition I used is given in the literature, for example, "Algebraic Topology from a Homotopical Viewpoint by Aguilar, Gitler and Prieto" definition 5.1.43. I'm assuming the "usual" definition is $f(X^n) \subset Y^n$ with $f(A^n) \subset B^n$?
